# C# Math.Pow(n,1/3) выдает 1, при любом n, как получить кубический корень?

Tags: c#

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
    double d = Math.Pow (n, 1/3);
    Console.WriteLine (d);
    Console.ReadKey ();
}
```

Если написать "Math.Pow (n, 1.0/3.0)" выводит число, близкое к правильному, если "Math.Pow (n, 0.3)" , то еще ближе.
Например, при вводе 3, в первом случае ~1.44, а во втором ~1,39.
Почему это происходит?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в том, что выражение `1/3` выполняет *целочисленное* деление. В C# деление целых чисел даёт целое число (тяжёлое наследие C++). Так что 1/3 == 0, и вы возводите по сути в нулевую степень.

Чтобы получить кубический корень, возводите-таки в степень 1.0/3.0. Полученный результат `1.4422495703074083` правильный. В доказательство перемножим его само на себя трижды:

```
var cuberoot3 = Math.Pow(3.0, 1.0/3.0);
Console.WriteLine(cuberoot3);
Console.WriteLine(cuberoot3 * cuberoot3 * cuberoot3);
```

Выводит:

> 1.44224957030741
>   3

http://ideone.com/dYGkCo

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. При вводе 9, выводит ~2,08. Почему не 2?

Comment: @r999 - потому что 2 - неправильный ответ. Воспользуйтесь калькулятором.

Comment: @r999: `2 * 2 * 2 = 8`, `2.08 * 2.08 * 2.08 = 8.99`.